# I'm not sure if this is considered a dual voltage this is a kdk a40as fan

Tags: motor, three-phase, fan

the motor

[image]

I am planning to connect this to a three phase rectifier but not sure if this is a dual voltage could anyone please help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please understand this is a Q&A, not a forum. As such, titles to questions should only include a brief summary of the question. You do not need to include greetings or mentions that you need help (we infer that help is needed simply because you are asking a question).